# Accessing a tab navigator from child element

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

In my main application mxml I am using a tab navigator,I can access that tab navigator anywhere in the application  by following code..

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.menuOption.selectedIndex=0;
```

Now my problem is I ihave used a toggle button bar in **transactionUI**  which is a child element of tab navigator ,How can i access that element like above mentioned code??

**My main mxml tab navigator ::**

```
<mx:TabNavigator   left="10" top="20" bottom="10" right="10" id="menuOption" >

    <ui1:homeUI label="Home" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#373737" chromeColor="#181818" contentBackgroundColor="#181818" color="#FDFDFD" /> 

    <ui1:transactionUI label="Transaction" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#373737"  />     

        <ui1:calanderUI label="Employee service" width="100%" height="100%"  horizontalCenter="0"  backgroundColor="#373737" chromeColor="#181818" contentBackgroundColor="#181818" color="#FDFDFD" />
        <ui1:ManagementUI label="Management" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#373737" chromeColor="#181818" contentBackgroundColor="#181818" color="#FDFDFD" />
        <ui1:reportUI label="Reports" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#373737" chromeColor="#181818" contentBackgroundColor="#181818" color="#FDFDFD" />

        <ui1:admin label="Admin" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#373737" chromeColor="#181818" contentBackgroundColor="#181818" color="#FDFDFD" />

    </mx:TabNavigator>
```

**My toggle bar inside transactionUI** ::

```
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%"
                xmlns:ui="com.colan.*" xmlns:ui1="com.colan.ui.*"
                backgroundColor="#373737" chromeColor="#181818" 
                contentBackgroundColor="#181818" color="#FDFDFD">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.*;
        import mx.core.*;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center"  verticalAlign="middle" width="100%"  height="100%">

    <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center"  verticalAlign="middle" width="100%"  height="15%" >

        <mx:ToggleButtonBar id="toggleButtonBar"
                            dataProvider="{viewStack}"    
                            selectedButtonTextStyleName="mySelectedButtonTextStyleName"
                            />


    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center"  verticalAlign="middle" width="100%"  height="85%" >


        <mx:ViewStack id="viewStack"                 
                      visible="{toggleButtonBar.selectedIndex > -1}" width="100%"  height="100%" >

            <ui1:transaction label="Transaction"/>
            <ui1:addClient label="Add  Client"/>
            <ui1:invoice label="Make invoice"/>
            <ui1:workCatalogue label="Work catalogue"/>
            <ui1:productCataloge label="Products Categories"/>

            <ui1:suppliers label="Offers"/>
            <ui1:calendarPlanUI label="Calendar"/>


        </mx:ViewStack>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

Please advice me...

Comment: Are you trying to access the child of the tab navigator globally or are you trying to access the tab navigator from the child? Your title says one thing but your post says another. Just another word of advice, your code is going to be very unmanageable very quickly if you do everything with globals. You really should think about adding some kind of data model or framework for communication across different parts of your application.

Comment: you shouldn't.  look up MVC frameworks and pick one.  Trying to access one view from another will ultimately cause breaks later.  OOP tries to prevent this with design patterns like MVC.

Answer (score 1):

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is meant to access the public variables/functions in your main application screen from any of its child screens.

For example..
If "transactionUI" NavigatorContent's ToggleButtonBar "calendarPlanUI" is for migrating to the main application "calanderUI" NavigatorContent.
Then you can straight away mention it then and there like

```
<ui1:calendarPlanUI label="Calendar" click="mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.menuOption.selectedIndex = '2'"/>
```

But if by any chance you are trying for toggleButtonBar like this

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.toggleButtonBar.selectedIndex = 1;
```

then I would like to mention that the main application's variables/functions/components can only be accessed using "topLevelApplication". Without creating an instance to transactionUI, you won't be able to use toggleButtonBar in other child screens/main app too.